# Implementing my own arrow helper in Three.js

Tags: three.js, quaternions

I would like to be able to draw arrows in Three.js with variable thickness, possibly with other customizations.  As far as I have found from searching, this cannot easily be done with `ArrowHelper`, so it looks like I should build it from scratch using the TubeGeometry.  For now I'm focused on just making the line portion, and for this I have written the following.

The basic idea is to start by making a tube with the specified dimensions.  By default I believe Three.js draws this in the y-axis.  But the inputs should allow you to give its initial position `ox, oy, oz` and terminal position `tx, ty, tz`.  So what I'm ultimately going to ask is, how I can set its position correctly.

```
export function customArrow( tx, ty, tz, ox=0, oy=0, oz=0, color='white', thickness=.1, head=.2 ) {
    const ovec = new THREE.Vector3( ox,oy,oz );
    const tvec = new THREE.Vector3( tx,ty,tz );
    const geom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( thickness, thickness, (ovec-tvec).length(), 50);
    const mater = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: color} );
    const cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geom, mater );
    const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
}
```

As I understand what I've seen, it is recommended to do rotations using quaternions.  And the way to use quaternions in Three.js is to specify a rotation axis and then rotation angle.  Therefore in this case, I need to take the cross-product of the vector with coordinates `x=tx-ox, y=ty-oy, z=tz-oz` with the vector `0,1,0`.  By my calculations, this is always just the vector `z,0,-x`.

The question is then: How do I find the angle of rotation about this axis, which would send `0,1,0` to `x,y,z`?

And a follow-up question: This seems like perhaps a lot of calculation.  I guess maybe it's all optimized behind-the-scenes in Three.js.  But it also kinda seems like there maybe should be some way around this without all the calculation?  I dunno, it just seems like this kind of thing would be common enough that there might be some other, more optimized solution.  So am I doing this in an optimal way?